# Facing Issue on Qml list view with textinput

Tags: qt, listview, qml, textinput, qt-quick

I am new to QML and I am facing a problem in `ListView` and `TextInput` types.

I am trying to create a `ListView` whose `delegate` contains `TextInput`. I'm able to correctly set the current select item of the `ListView` but the contained `TextInput` does not receive focus, i.e. cursor is not positioning on it. Here is my current code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item{
    width:360
    height:360

    Rectangle{
        id:title
        //bottom: parent.bottom
        //      anchors.
        anchors.top:parent.top
        height: 40
        width: 360
        border.width: 2
        color: "grey"
        Text {
            id: txt
            //bottom: parent.bottom
            height: title.height
            width:title.width
            text:"This is the List View"
            anchors.centerIn: parent                  
        }
    }

    Component{
        id:comp

        Item{   
            id:rect
            width: 100
            height: 50

            Column{
                anchors.centerIn: parent

                TextInput{
                    x:1
                    id:textinputid1
                    focus: true
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    cursorPosition: 0
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    text:"hello"

                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id:listrect
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - 50
        x: 30
        anchors.top: title.bottom

        ListView{
            id:list
            anchors.top: title.bottom
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height - 20
            focus: true
            model: mymodel
            delegate: comp

            highlight: Rectangle{color: "green";radius: 5}          
        }  
    }

    ListModel{
        id:mymodel
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan"
        }
        ListElement{ 
            //name:"Chan2"
        }
        ListElement{
            //name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Chan3"
        }   
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you describe step-by-step what you want to achieve? Pictures help as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `QtQuick.2`? Also, next time, please format your code before pasting here. Remove commented code, unnecessary empty lines and spaces. Post only code related to the problem.

As for your problem, try this:

```js
Component{
    id:comp

    Item{
        id:rect
        property int currentIndex: index // store item index
        Column{
            TextInput {
                //focus: true // not needed
                onFocusChanged: {
                    if(focus)
                        list.currentIndex = rect.currentIndex; // set list current index when TextInput focused
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```